# Adjoining binary trees

Tags: ocaml

I am writing a function that takes 2 binary trees (t1 and t2) and generates a new tree that places t2 at the bottom right of t1. t2 is attached to the first node whose right child is empty, even if the node is not a leaf.

```
let rec adjoin_right (t1: 'a tree) (t2: 'a tree) : 'a tree
```

test case:

```
let test () : bool =
adjoin_right (Node (Empty, 1, Empty)) (Node (Empty, 2, Empty)) = 
Node(Empty, 1, Node (Empty, 2, Empty))
;; run_test "adjoin_right leaf" test
```

Can somebody steer me in the right direction for this problem? I know that I'll probably have to write a helper function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make recursion work you just have to think about two questions:

- What's the result supposed to be if `t1` is `Empty`?
- If `t1` isn't empty, but you had a function that worked properly when applied to the subtrees of `t1`, how would you use this function to get the result?

If you can figure these out, then you do have a function that works properly for subtrees.

**Edit**

Consider the recursive case. You have `l` (your left subtree), `r` (your right subtree), and `v` (the value in the node). In FP you're not going to change any of these values. What you want to do is to construct a *new* tree with the correct contents. So, how would you use your function recursively to make the new tree from these three ingredients? It's not hard--really just one line of code.

Comment: great, thanks! would i need a helper method in this instance?

Comment: I don't see a need for a helper function, but if you do--go for it.

Comment: I was able to figure out the result when t1 is Empty. But I'm not quite sure how to figure out the recursive part.

Comment: I don't want to just write your code for you :-) I'll add a hint or two--see **Edit**.

Comment: FWIW, I would avoid posting the right answer. You're answering everybody else's homework for them. Just a thought. Good work, otherwise!